# @OneToOne or @OneToMany references an unkown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy

I'm having some issues with an error that occurs from time to time on my project. I have some JPA entities in project 1 that are used on project 2.

I'm using micronaut (groovy), liquibase and hibernate.

The error I get is as follows:

```
2022-03-07 09:44:18.513 xxxxx-xxx-xxx ERROR [xxxxx-xxx,,,] [,,||||,]   --- [           main] i.m.c.h.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBean     : Hibernate mapping error
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on root.company.library1.domain.process.actor.ActorCreationProcess.actorType references an unknown entity: root.company.library1.domain.actor.ActorType
```

The entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'actor_creation_process')
class ActorCreationProcess extends BaseEntity {

@JoinColumn(name = 'actor_type_id')
@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = ActorType)
ActorType actorType

}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name='actor_type')
class ActorType extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    UUID id

    @Column (nullable = false)
    String name

}
```

The superclass "BaseEntity" is as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7933099518124664248L

    @Column
    LocalDateTime createdAt

    @Column
    LocalDateTime updatedAt

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
}
```

Sometimes I'll execute it and it won't throw the error.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Specified I'm using Groovy and BaseEntity specification.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that base entity as the following

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {}
```

Also,
make sure that target entity refer to the mentioned entity from the same package not different package and it must refer to the **class** not the entity, i mean

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = ActorType.class)
ActorType actorType
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the BaseEntity specification has the annotation already. I'm using groovy so the .class is not needed. I've updated the question.

Comment: ActorType seems to be at the package that it is not scanned by the app, thus JPA/Hibernate is not aware of that Entity.

Comment: Thing is, the entity that throws the error sometimes changes, there are a few entities with the OneToMany or ManyToOne annotations, it doesn't seem to be always the same entities to fail